# Commas between subject and verb

Tags: commas

Apologies if this has been asked before, I don't know the linguistics lingo well enough to find an answer by searching.

Which of the following are incorrect, and why?

1. I eat cheese and he bread.
2. I eat cheese and he, bread.
3. I eat cheese, and he bread.
4. I eat cheese, and he, bread.

I have a vague sense of some of these being more natural than others (for instance, 3 seems wrong), but I'm not sure whether this feeling indicates style or correctness.

Comment: Personally, I'd go for the simple solution: “I eat cheese and he bread”. No comma needed at all. If you do want a comma, it should go between the two clauses: “I eat cheese, and he bread”.

Comment: I can't see a difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: I believe we would say it as in #4. FWIW.

Comment: Can you really delete the second verb when it's not in the same person as the first? The complete sentence would not be "I eat cheese and he eat bread", would it?

Comment: @Margana - In spoken English it would be, "I eat cheese, and he eats bread."  The sentence as presented looks archaic to me.

Comment: _Bread_ is not a verb. Neither is _and_. The comma is really a special intonation; if you hear it, write it; if you don't, don't. Also, in a sentence as short as this, commas are rarely used, except to emphasize a particular intonation pattern. And why delete the second _eat,_ anyway, if it leads to commatization problems?

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for that. I've learned a new word - commatization!

Comment: Yes; too much of it makes one commatose.

Comment: ...or a comma chameleon.

Comment: I like 1 (and 2: they're identical) or 4.

I don't like the substitution of "are" for "is:": "Which (one) of the following *is* correct?"

Comment: As Steven Pinker points in *The Sense of Style* commas can signal syntactic breaks, semantics breaks, and prosodic breaks (i.e., pauses in intonation): "Now, often these breaks line up:  a supplementary phrase, the kind that calls for a comma, is typically preceded and followed by a pause.  But often they do not line up, and that lays out a minefield for an inexperienced or inattentive writer."  If-you-hear-it-write it-if-you-don't- don't is terrible advice to give a novice.

Comment: How about "I eat bread and she goats"?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Edited.